# how to fix this : Trying to access array offset on value of type null while deploying to heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

below is my helper.php code

sometimes the app works with the same set of code but sometimes it show this error.

```
//get json setting as array

if (!function_exists('setting')) 
{  
function setting($key)
{
    $setting=Setting::where('key',$key)->first();
    **$setting=json_decode($setting['value'],true);** //<- error in this line

    return $setting;
}
```

}

it only shows when I migrate my database by PHP artisan migrate. and if I don't migrate my database and jus deploy the app its shows the laravel web installer but in the 3rd step its hows permission 775 error below:

[image: error while deploying to heroku]